# Browserless API protection with IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I've studied the OAuth2 and OpenId Connect protocols to secure resources, but something doesn't feel right.

How do you allow simple and direct access to an API protected by IdentityServer4?

The use case: the user needs to consume my REST API directly, no browser involved (for example, via Postman).

As simple as that:

1. The user sends a request with his username and password to the identity provider to generate an access token.
2. He uses that access token (as bearer) and consumes the API.

But, there are some complications along the way, like providing client secrets and scope to the identity provider to generate the token (the user should be concerned only with his username and password, not notions about scopes and etc). Maybe OAuth2/OpenId Connect are not the right tool for the job?

Comment: Although you can achieve requesting tokens using Postman. You should never ask for a password in a client (e.g. Postman). You should redirect the user to the authorization server instead.

Comment: I see, so how should a browser-less flow happen? It's all REST, plain API calls, no browser involved.

Comment: OpenId Connect does not have any process with browserless. If you must use password and user, you need customize another authentication by yourself. If your website need open for outside user, you need use two authentications, OpenId Connect  works for outside and another authentication(e.g. window authentication) for intenal user.

Comment: "Authorization Code Flow" is for browser users. But there are other kinds of oauth flows https://frontegg.com/blog/oauth-flows

Answer (score 0):

For machine-to-machine communication where you have no user involved, then you can us the client credentials flow. However, if you are dealing with external users that you don't know, you should use the authorization code flow and let the user login in the client using the browser. Then the client will receive back a id/access and refresh token and using the access token, then the client can access the API without human involvement.

The client can use the refresh token to get new access token when it is about to expire.